# Get number(decimal digit) from String

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I see somebody already asked this question but the result is not really in the case of number is decimal digit.

Example:

```
var str = "textsometext13.523 after text";
```

Then if I use `str.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');`

It will return `13523` instead of `13.523`

How I can use new regex to get it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Add `.` to your regex? `/[^0-9.]/gi` - But note that doing a global replace means that if the input was `"text 13.523 text 12"` the output would be `13.52312`... (Note also that this is a JavaScript question, not a jQuery question.)

Comment: @nnnnnn what does `.` mean on this regex

Comment: @guradio - It means the literal `.` character (because it is within `[]`).

Comment: right. I think it helps me :). Thanks. Please give your answer to give best answer. Is possible to get two numbers or more if they separate by space or text?

Comment: i think reverse process more easy `console.log("textsometext13.523 after text".replace(/[a-z]/g,""))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know your input string will only contain one number and not have a full stop at the end then simply update your regex to include a `.` in the list of characters to keep:

```
/[^0-9.]/gi
```

But if you need to allow for input like the following:

```
"text 123.12 text 13"
"The numbers are 132.12, 144.11, and 123.1."
```

...then you should use the [`.match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), which with the right regex will return an array of matched numbers (or return `null` if there were no matches):

```
var results = input.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g);
```

That is, match one or more digits `\d+`, that are optionally followed by a decimal `\.` and one or more digits `\d+`.

Demo:

```js
console.log( "text 123.12 text".match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g) );
console.log( "The numbers are 132.12, 5, and 123.1.".match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g) );
console.log( "No numbers".match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g) );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `RegExp` `/\d+\.\d+|\d+/g` to match digits followed by `.` character followed by digits, or one or more digits

```
str.match(/\d+\.\d+|\d+/g)
```

Comment: @hwnd Both approaches return same result, yes? fwiw current approach saves two characters.

Answer (score 1):

simply use like this `/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g`:

```js
console.log("textsometext13.523 after text".match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g,""))
```

Alternate, its the reverse process replace the `[a-z]` same thing will append

```js
console.log("textsometext13.523 after text".replace(/[a-z]/g,""))
```

Comment: in your first snippet, `.` represents any character, you need to escape it: `\.`

Comment: What if the string contains characters other than letters and digits? `"This is a number: 13.523. Thanks..."`

Comment: @nnnnnn the first snippet uses a particular pattern to avoid that

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
var string = "textsometext13.523 after text";
var number =  string.match(/[\d\.]+/).toString();
var num = number.split('.');
alert(num[1]); //display the numbers after the period(.) symbol
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should match any number whether it has a decimal or not:

> ```
> /(\d*\.?\d*)/g
> ```

#### SNIPPET

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var inp1 = document.getElementById('inp1');
var out1 = document.getElementById('out1');


btn1.onclick = function() {
  var str = inp1.value
  var res = str.match(/\d*\.?\d*/g);
  out1.innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<input id='inp1'>
<input id='btn1' type='button' value='Extract Numbers'>
<output id='out1'></output>
```